# How to create a sequential promise loop with variable function calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, promise

I need to somehow loop over the `work` array passed to `_start` then 
for each of the items in the array, I need to somehow call the corresponding function with the same name.

I don't have control over the number of items in `work` the array or the number of items, I do know that there will always be a corresponding function.

I don't want to call all the functions at the same time, once the first function resolves after 3 seconds, I then want to call the second function, once the second function resolves after 3 seconds I then want to call the third function. Once the third function resolves after another 3 seconds I want to call _done().

In this example each function takes 3 seconds to complete `_done` wont gete called for 9 seconds.

```
function _start(data){
    // Insert some kinda native magic loop
}


function _one(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            resolve(1); 
        }, 3000);
    })
};


function _two(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            resolve(2); 
        }, 3000);
    })
};

function _done(){
    console.log('All done in 9 seconds)
}


(function(){
    var work = ['_one', '_two', '_two'];
    _start(work);
})();
```

Comment: In the use case I have I don't know the order or number of items in the `work` array. I do know that they will have a corresponding function with the same name

Comment: And the environment is the latest node.js install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the order is dicated by the array, you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to aggregate the promises into a chain

```
const _start = (...actions) => {
  return actions.reduce((chain, action) => {
    const func = this[action];
    return chain.then(() => func());
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
...
_start('_one', '_two', '_three').then(() => console.log('All done'));
```

See it [in action](https://repl.it/Mcjj/0) - the example appends an extra `then` to the chain just to output any results from the promises (probably outwith the scope of this question but something you may have to consider if getting data back is required).

**Update**

Can see you intend on invoking `_start` from a different context in which the functions are declared, this is fine but you need to make sure you set the correct context before hand i.e.

```
const self = this;
(function() {
  _start.bind(self)('_one', '_two', '_two');
})();
```

Comment: hey James this looks good, the delay i added to each function was just to simulate some async call that I don't really know how long it would take to return

Comment: @Bill ah ok I thought that was a specific rule i.e. only run next action after X seconds of the prev finishing. That's fine, you can omit that part, the only downside of this at the minute is getting the results from the actions out (i.e. `resolve(1)` etc.). Would you need to get values back from these promises? If so I would need to update the solution to aggregate those too.

Comment: @torazaburo yeah was toying with that idea, or firing the first Promise in the chain....think your right though, just keeps the code consistent.

Comment: @Bill stripped out the delay code, if it's not required then it was just polluting the solution.

Comment: Will using Promise.all call all the functions at the same time? or will it wait for the first one to finish before calling the next one in the 'work' array

Comment: @Bill ignore `Promise.all`, that's a mistake, you will only ever have a single Promise here so `_start.then(...)` would be fine.

Comment: Is `() => func()` different somehow than `func`?

Comment: @Bill added a link to a demo

Comment: const func = this[action];
                                 ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_one' of undefined

Comment: @torazaburo really more for a cleaner API because we don't want params from the previous promise being passed to the next....although this would be a nice way to chain the results if that was a requirement! :)

Comment: @Bill `this` being undefined would be a scoping problem, see the demo for an example of the code running. The assumption here is all these functions are part of the same context (i.e. they are all declared the same object/function/class). If that isn't the case you will either need to bind the context via `_start(...).bind(context)` or alternatively pass a ref into `_start` (`bind` is cleaner though).

Comment: @James I changed the function to take arguments, and added in some time outs to simulate async calls to an API. all the promises are returning at the same time instead of one after the other seen here. https://repl.it/MeHl/7

Comment: @Bill your example isn't correct, you don't take a ref to the func inside reduce, your actually invoking it immediately i.e. `const func = this[action.functionToCall](action.argumentToSend)` <- this will fire the promise. Either pass the argument into the func inside the `then` part or convert your functions to be [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to avoid them firing immediately.

Answer (score 1):

A function which creates a promise which sleeps:

```
const sleep = n => () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, n));
```

A function which sleeps after some input promise:

```
const sleepAfter = n => p => p.then(sleep(n));
```

A function which chains a bunch of promises, represented by functions:

```
const chain = (...promises) => promises.reduce((ret, promise) => ret.then(promise), 
  Promise.resolve());
```

Run a bunch of functions yielding promises, sleeping in between:

```
const _start = promises => chain(promises.map(sleepAfter(3000)));
```

Now just:

```
_start(_one, _two, _three).then(_done);
```

Comment: Part of the challenge was the promises were a string array and not the actual refs. Two ways around it, you either map inside `chain` (assuming the context is the same, which it would appear to be) or alternatively you map outside i.e. `_start([...].map(a => this[a]))`

Comment: FWIW `ret.then(promise())` should be `ret.then(promise)` otherwise all your promises would start at the same time and not in order. Also missing a closing bracket on your `_start` / `sleep` funcs.

Comment: @James Thanks for the pointers, typos fixed. As for providing the functions in string form, I did not take this to be part of the spec for this problem, since referring to JS values by their string name is tricky at best and impossible at worst.

Answer (score -2):

Try using this:

```
_one().then((firstResponse) {
      return_two();
}) .then((secondResponse) => {
 *second and first respone are already done*

});
```

Comment: This would work great if i knew the order and number of items on the work array, how could i get this to work if I don't?

Answer (score -3):

Use `promises` `then`

```
_one().then((responseOne) => {
    return _two();
}).then((responseTwo) => {
    // _one & _two are done
});
```

Comment: This would work great if i knew the order and number of items on the work array, how could i get this to work if I don't?